# Offering Madhuparka in Kali yuga

Tags: rituals, kali-yuga, cows

The footnote in this chapter in Skanda Purana text says

> According to Bṛhatparāśara Smṛti the following five are to be eschewed in Kali Age: procreation of a child from husband’s brother (if the husband is dead and is childless), killing of a beast (viz cow or calf), **Madhuparka for the reception of a guest,** serving of meat in Śrāddha, and entrance into Vānaprastha stage of life.

My question is on Madhuparka; as this is offered even today in rituals and ceremonies like wedding.

Is the prohibition only on offering cow (as discussed in this forum about killing of cows)

Comment: You likely mistranslated the sloka. Only slaughtering of animals FOR preparing madhuparka is prohibited, not offering Madhuparka itself.